# Use of gender-specific and gender-neutral words together

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sexual-minorities

These are sample sentences we usually come across:

> 1. This is a **husband**'s provision for **his spouse**.
> 2. This is a **wife**'s provision for **her spouse**.

One may find a similar sentence reading "A **husband**’s (or **wife**’s) provision for **a spouse** after separation or divorce" at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alimony

"Husband" and "wife" are gender-specific words, while "spouse" is a gender-neutral word. Logic says that when a gender-specific word "husband" or "wife" is used in a sentence, the opposite of that word in the sentence should also be gender-specific (and should not be a gender-neutral word). If so, then how could one use gender-specific and gender-neutral words together in the sentences like the ones cited above? Or, how could there be a sentence like the one cited at the link provided above?

To me, the correct sentences would be:

> 1. This is a husband's provision for his wife.
> 2. This is a wife's provision for her  husband.

Or, one could perhaps also say:

> 1. This is a spouse's provision for the other spouse.
> 2. This is a spouse's provision for the other.

I admit that I may be wrong. Can someone shed some light?

Comment: In many countries nowadays, a husband may have a husband or a wife may have a wife. However, there is a separate reason for the sentence in the Oxford dictionary: it's longer and more complicated to write "A husband’s (or wife’s) provision for a wife (or a husband) after separation or divorce."

Comment: I'm not sure what logic you are referring to, but I don't get it. Also, I don't see where "opposites" come into play with regard to spouses. The usual idea is that they are a union.

Comment: I've just checked "a husband's provision for his spouse" for Google hits. Zero, if you discount the two generated here. Please justify 'These are sample sentences we usually come across:'. Note that "A husband’s (or wife’s) provision for a spouse" needs the gender-neutral term after the disjunctive "A husband’s (or wife’s)"; this example _is_ logical.

Comment: I see you haven't responded. I've just returned here via another search. Your 'Logic says that when a gender-specific word "husband" or "wife" is used in a sentence, the opposite of that word in the sentence should also be gender-specific (and should not be a gender-neutral word).' begs the question. You're confusing referent and token. Obviously when single-sex marriages were the only ones recognised, a 'husband' could only have a female as partner, a 'wife'. But that logic doesn't extend to the allowable choice of words to describe the situation: 'mate' or 'partner' are quite acceptable.